# How can I choose to update a particular view with a JSON request

Tags: android, json, parsing, android-fragments

```
    public class AdapterQuestion extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterQuestion.ViewQuestion>{
    private LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;
    private ArrayList<QuestionData> mListblogs =new ArrayList<>();
    public AdapterQuestion(Context context){

        mLayoutInflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);

    }
    public void setBloglist(ArrayList<QuestionData> listBlogs){
        this.mListblogs =listBlogs;
        notifyItemRangeChanged(0, listBlogs.size());
    }

    @Override
    public ViewQuestion onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view= mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.customquestion, null);
        ViewQuestion holder=new ViewQuestion(view);
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewQuestion holder, int position) {
        QuestionData currentBlog= mListblogs.get(position);
        holder.answerText.setText(currentBlog.getMtext());
        holder.answerId.setText(currentBlog.getId());
        holder.mVotes.setText(currentBlog.getVotes());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mListblogs.size();
    }

    public static class ViewQuestion extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        private TextView answerText;
        private TextView answerId;
        private TextView mVotes;
        private LikeButton mLikeButton;

        public ViewQuestion (View view){
            super(view);
            answerText=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.answerText);
            answerId=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.answerId);
            mVotes=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.VoteTextView);
            mLikeButton=(LikeButton)itemView.findViewById(R.id.heart_buttons);

            mLikeButton.setOnLikeListener(new OnLikeListener() {
                @Override
                public void liked(LikeButton likeButton) {
                    Voting vote = new Voting();
                    vote.onUpVote(convertToString(),mVotes);
                }
                @Override
                public void unLiked(LikeButton likeButton) {
                    Voting onDown=new Voting();
                    onDown.onDownVote(convertToString());
                }
            });

        }
        public String getVoteView(){
            String voteView=mVotes.getText().toString();
            return voteView;
        }
        public String convertToString(){
            String converted=answerId.getText().toString();
            return converted;
        }
    }
}

    public class Voting {

    public void onUpVote(String Id,final TextView VoteView) {
        final RequestQueue mrequestQueue = VolleySingleton.getInstance().getRequestQueue();
        final String PUT_VOTE_UP = "url";
        StringRequest PostVoteUp = new StringRequest(Request.Method.PUT, PUT_VOTE_UP, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                VoteView.setText("likes");
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        });
        mrequestQueue.add(PostVoteUp);
        System.out.println("VOTED UP");
    }
    public void onDownVote( String Id) {
        final RequestQueue mrequestQueue = VolleySingleton.getInstance().getRequestQueue();
        final String PUT_VOTE_DOWN = "url";
        StringRequest PostVoteUp = new StringRequest(Request.Method.PUT, PUT_VOTE_DOWN, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {

            }

        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("************Answer" + error + "error");
            }
        });
        mrequestQueue.add(PostVoteUp);
        System.out.println("VOTED DOWN");
    }

}
```

I have Two classes, an adapter class for my fragment activity and a voting class. I am calling the voting class in my adapter class when a user presses a button, However, I also have a JSON request and a parse method in my fragment activity as shown below and I would like to only update the "votes" when the button is pressed How can I do this?

```
private ArrayList<QuestionData> parseJSONResponseQuestion(JSONArray response) {
    if (!response.equals("")) {
        ArrayList<QuestionData> questionDataArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            StringBuilder data = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject currentQuestions = response.getJSONObject(i);
                String text = currentQuestions.getString("text");
                String votes = currentQuestions.getString("votes");
                int voteInt=Integer.parseInt(votes);
                QuestionData questionData = new QuestionData();
                questionData.setMtext(text);
                questionData.setVotes(votes);
            }
            System.out.println(data.toString());
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return mListblogs;
}
```

Comment: post a little more detail

Comment: Are you asking about updating the listView data with the json? its hard to understand what you are trying to achieve

Comment: its a recyclerview

Comment: as u can tell it says  extends RecyclerView.Adapter

Comment: Thats irrelevant, just trying to understand your question.

Comment: @Nanoc well from that u would know its a recyclerview....

Answer (score 1):

**First** you should add a method into your adapter for updating single QuestionData. For example:

```
public void setBlogItem(int index, QuestionData questionData) {
    if (mListblogs.get(index).getVotes() != questionData.getVotes()) {
        mListblogs.set(index, questionData);
        notifyItemChanged(index);
    }
}
```

Second. Update question. For doing this you have to know index of the item. I suggest that the whole list doesn't change. So, modify your json parser:

```
private ArrayList<QuestionData> parseJSONResponseQuestion(JSONArray response) {
    if (!response.equals("")) {
        ArrayList<QuestionData> questionDataArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            StringBuilder data = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject currentQuestions = response.getJSONObject(i);
                String text = currentQuestions.getString("text");
                String votes = currentQuestions.getString("votes");
                int voteInt=Integer.parseInt(votes);
                QuestionData questionData = new QuestionData();
                questionData.setMtext(text);
                questionData.setVotes(votes);
                recyclerAdapter.setBlogItem(i, questionData); /// Put attention here!
            }
            System.out.println(data.toString());
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return mListblogs;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**I'm assuming you're using a `LinearLayoutManager` for your `RecyclerView`.**

Pass the clicked position from your `ViewQuestion's` `onClick()` to your `onUpVote()` and `onDownVote()` methods.

From the `onUpVote()` and `onDownVote()` methods, post a `Broadcast` specifying whatever data in your `intent.putExtras` and also include the clicked position.

Now on your `Activity`, write a `BroadcastReceiver` which captures the `broadcasts` sent from the `onUpVote()` or `onDownVote()` methods. Now from the `Activity`, call your 
`LinearLayoutManager.findViewByPosition(position)` method to get a reference to your `View` which was clicked. Now you can use `findViewById()` method to find your required `view` and update the values.

Comment: Dude, that is by no means an efficient way to do this

Comment: Hi Eli. Well, it's not that inefficient as you think. I think u get the idea that it's difficult to communicate with activities otherwise! That's the only thing which came to my mind! Lol!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your application needs a bit of architecture work. Have you considered restricting your use of JSON to only when you need to read or write the data to a file or network or something similar.  If your mixing JSON up in your model then you might be writing much more code than you need.

Just a thought ...